# Buttons not maintaining size constraints in StackView

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

I am working on the Implementing A Custom Control iOS tutorial (I would link it but I'm not allowed to use more than two links).

I am at the point where I have 5 buttons generate within a StackView. I implemented these constraints for each button:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
```

I entered all code exactly as specified, but when I run the app, the buttons fill the stack view vertically and horizontally:

[image]

If I set the StackView's alignment property to Top, I can prevent the buttons from stretching vertically, but the last button is still stretched horizontally:

[image]

I have tried many different methods for preventing the last button being stretched to no avail. In the console, I see that the size constraints are being overridden, but I cannot figure out by what.

I would like these buttons to maintain the specified height and width (44) within the StackView. Any ideas on how to do this? I can give more info if needed.

Comment: Can you try deleting this `button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried that and it gives the same results.

Comment: What are the attributes of your stack view?

Comment: Hopefully [this](http://imgur.com/a/0Pn6D) is what you're looking for. Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: Try the **Distribution** property of stack view with `Fill Equally` or `Fill Proportionally`.

Comment: Fill Equally gives the buttons equal widths, but stretches each one so that the whole stack view is filled horizontally. Fill Proportionally does not appear to change anything.

Comment: " last button is still stretched horizontally" because last button is not equal width as the other buttons.

Comment: Yes but I set the same width constraint for all of them. It is getting overridden for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it's working fine.

```
-(void)makeFiveButton {

UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIButton *button3 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
button3.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UIButton *button4 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
button4.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
UIButton *button5 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
button5.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];



UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc]init];
stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFill;
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentFill;
stackView.spacing = 10;


[stackView addArrangedSubview:button1];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:button2];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:button3];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:button4];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:button5];
[self.view addSubview:stackView];

button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
button5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


[button1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;
[button1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;

[button2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;
[button2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;

[button3.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;
[button3.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;

[button4.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;
[button4.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;

[button5.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;
[button5.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44].active = true;

[stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
[stackView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;

}
```

Comment: Sorry for objective C.

Comment: Looking through your code, mine was identical except I hadn't set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to false for the stack view itself. That fixed the resizing issue, but made all the buttons appear at the top of the window. I had to add constraints for the stack view spacing from other elements in the window, and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for the unusually pleasant looking Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the selected answer did not work for me. I was able to fix it by setting the alignment to leading and distrbution to equalSpacing:

```
private func setupButtons() {
    // My Fix
    self.alignment = .leading
    self.distribution = .equalSpacing

    for _ in 0..<5 {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
}
```

OR through IB:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

everything will work later, if you follow manual

Comment: This helps a lot.